# TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react. Now I am Facing a problem. My app is running well(simple e-commerce). But the problem is When I am entering shipping address to checkout process it throws an error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of null.**

I am using redux.So when I delete the existing address from browsers Localstorage it runs well.[Error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrIpQ.png)

**Shipping Screen**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { saveShippingAddress } from "../actions/cartActions";
import CheckoutSteps from "../components/CheckoutSteps";
import FormContainer from "../components/FormContainer";

const ShippingScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { shippingAddress } = cart;

 

  const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingAddress.address);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(shippingAddress.city);
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState(shippingAddress.postalCode);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(shippingAddress.country);

 const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(saveShippingAddress({ address, city, postalCode, country }));
    history.push("/payment");
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 />
      <h1>Shipping</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId="address">
          <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter address"
            value={address}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="city">
          <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter city"
            value={city}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="postalCode">
          <Form.Label>Postal Code</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter postal code"
            value={postalCode}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="country">
          <Form.Label>Country</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter country"
            value={country}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
          Continue
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

export default ShippingScreen;
```

**cartReducer.js**

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM, CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [],shippingAddress:{} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item = action.payload;
      const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);
      if (existItem) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
            x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
        };
      }

    case CART_REMOVE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product !== action.payload),
      };

      case CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        shippingAddress: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**cartAction.js**

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM, CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [],shippingAddress:{} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item = action.payload;
      const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);
      if (existItem) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
            x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
        };
      }

    case CART_REMOVE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product !== action.payload),
      };

      case CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        shippingAddress: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```js
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';
import { productDetailsReducers, productListReducers } from './reducers/productReducers';
import { userDetailsReducer, userLoginReducer, userRegisterReducer, userUpdateProfileReducer } from './reducers/userReducers';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducers,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducers,
  cart: cartReducer,
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfile:userUpdateProfileReducer
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
  : [];

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  : null;


  const shippingAddressFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAdress'))
  : {};

const initialState = {
  cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage,
    shippingAddress:shippingAddressFromStorage },
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

**store.js**

Comment: `shippingAddress` is null.

Comment: Is this question connected to this other one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470059/reactreduxtypeerror-cannot-read-property-address-of-null/

Comment: thanks find it's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have miss spelled

```
const shippingAddressFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingA>d<ress'))
  : {};
```

here..This should be 'shippingAddress'.I did the similar mistake previously.

Answer (score 0):

```
const shippingAddressFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')
? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress'))
: {};
```

**shippingAddress !== shippingAdress**